# What is the Youtube OAuth 2.0 user token validity period?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I read the documentation in the Youtube developers website it does not talk about any validity.
Does the OAuth 2.0 standards define any validity period or is the authorization token valid till the user revokes it manually ?
The [OAuth spec](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg04553.html) defines that the token should expire shortly after its granted, so will it expire after I get the
access and refresh tokens ?
And can I use this access token for all future API requests or do I need to get a new token periodically ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are talking about the **authorization code**, you're mixing the terms a bit here.

From the [OAuth 2.0 draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.1.2):

> The authorization code MUST expire shortly after it is issued to mitigate the risk of leaks. A maximum authorization code lifetime of 10 minutes is RECOMMENDED. The client MUST NOT use the authorization code more than once. If an authorization code is used more than once, the authorization server MUST deny the request and SHOULD revoke (when possible) all tokens previously issued based on that authorization code.

After using it once for getting the **access token**, you can not use it again. You also don't need to retrieve an **authorization code** periodically. You do this only when you have no **access token** for a user, but want to request his data.

Your **access token** some time expires. You know when by either looking at the `expires_in` value that got send with it, or by doing a request to the API and getting an *access token expired* error back. Then you can use the **refresh token** to get a new **access token** without the user being involved.

Answer (score 1):

Very useful step-by-step guide about how to get access and fresh tokens and save them for future use using YouTube OAuth API v3. 
[PHP server-side YouTube V3 OAuth API video upload guide](https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide).
The good thing is, you do not need to worry about the expiry of the tokens, as the script in this guide checks, saves, and updates the token in a txt file for future access.

```
{"access_token":"XXXXXXXXX","token_type":"Bearer", "expires_in":3600, "refresh_token":"XXXXXXX", "created":000000}
```

We use at http://presentationtube.com and it works fine with thousands of users.